# How can I make a double-headed arrow with math equation labelled?

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to acquire something to this effect.

[image]

Using

```
\xrightarrow
```

I have been able to do this roughly, but I'd like the double headed version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The extensible arrows `\xleftarrow` and `\xrightarrow` are defined by `amsmath`. Its extension `mathtools`  defines also the double-headed version `\xleftrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
A \xleftrightarrow{\text{loooong stuff}} B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version without `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\xleftrightarrow[1]{%
  \mathbin{\ooalign{$\,\xrightarrow{#1}$\cr$\xleftarrow{\hphantom{#1}}\,$}}
}
\begin{document}
\[
A \xrightarrow{\varphi} B \xrightarrow{\text{PDQ Bach}} C
\]
\[
A \xleftrightarrow{\varphi} B \xleftrightarrow{\text{PDQ Bach}} C
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it in `\scriptstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\newcommand\xleftrightarrow[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \mathbin{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle\,\xrightarrow{#1}$\cr
                    $\SavedStyle\xleftarrow{\hphantom{#1}}\,$}}
}}
\begin{document}
\[
A \xrightarrow{\varphi} B \xrightarrow{\text{PDQ Bach}} C
\]
\[
A \xleftrightarrow{\varphi} B \xleftrightarrow{\text{PDQ Bach}} C
\]
\[\scriptstyle
A \xleftrightarrow{\varphi} B \xleftrightarrow{\text{PDQ Bach}} C
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]