# In-in arrow like leftrightarrow

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

[image]I use `\overset\leftrightarrow{G}` to generate a double out-out arrow. However, after looking through several hudreds different lines in tex manual, I have not managed to find a way to generate a similar, but into-into double arrow. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a double-headed arrow with math equation labelled?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306645/how-can-i-make-a-double-headed-arrow-with-math-equation-labelled)

Comment: @egreg If I interpret "into-into double arrow" correctly I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: @gernot I can't interpret it in any other way.

Comment: Can you please add an approximate graphic representation of what you seek?

Comment: Can we take your question to mean that while `\leftrightarrow` (sort of) creates an `<-->` arrow (out-out), you want an `>--<` arrow (into-into)? A short mock-up graphic of what you are thinking of would be of help.

Comment: Can we assume you want something like `→←`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package stix has `\lefttail` and `\righttail`.  You can combine them like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{stix, amsmath}
\newcommand{\leftrighttail}{\mathbin{\rlap{$\righttail$}\lefttail}}
\begin{document}
$a \leftrighttail b$, $a\overset{G}{\leftrighttail} B$, 
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update* After your comment I understood that you wanted `\rightrightarrows` from `amssymb`.

Here you are

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\rightrightarrows}{G}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update 2*

After you added a picture, I understood what did you want.

Here you are.  We again use `stix` tails, but here we need to slightly adjust them.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{stix,mathtools}
\newcommand{\leftrighttailaccent}[1]{%
  \overset{{\mathrlap{\righttail}\mkern3mu\lefttail}}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\leftrighttailaccent{G}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, I need a slightly different thing. I need something like    $\vec{a}$    , but a kind of vector line with two in-in arrows rather than wit in out arrow.

Comment: Ok, please see update

Comment: thank you. Sorry for not providing the picture that I need in the beginning. I've just updated my question and added a picture I would like to have.

Comment: Ok, another update...